# Changing Name Of XML When Deserialising

Tags: c#

I have the following code snippet generated by the xsd tool:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class myCourseCourseStructureModule
```

I would like to call the class something a bit more meaningful. What attribute do I need to add to allow me to change this easily?

Answer (score 1):

XmlTypeAttribute has a constructor that takes a string which should be the name:
[XmlTypeAttribute Constructor on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/573s2dsz.aspx).  As described in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579982/xmltypeattribute-does-not-change-name-of-type), this will change the name of the complex type in the schema.  John Saunders suggests using

```
[XmlElement(Name="MyAddress", Namespace="your namespace")]
```

to change the element name in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

[XmlElementAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.elementname.aspx)

```
// This is the class that will be serialized.
public class XClass
{
   /* The XML element name will be XName
   instead of the default ClassName. */
   [XmlElement(ElementName = "XName")]
   public string ClassName;
}
```